# how to change classes in android.jar file

Tags: android

I am new to android programming.
I have got the Google native contact code and imported it in the eclipse IDE .
After importing there are errors in each and every Java file and errors are like, some classes are importing the other classes that is not in the project not even in `android.jar`.
So I have downloaded `android-apps-4.4_r1.jar` file and added it to the project(external jar). By doing this most of the errors have been removed but still there are many errors to remove.
e.g.: one class has been imported `android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactCounts`
and there is a class file in `android.jar` folder named `android.provider.ContactsContract` but I think there is not any variable `ContactCounts` in that file, so I have searched this file (`android.provider.ContactsContract`) in the Internet and there I found it so my question is how to replace that class file (exist in `android.jar` folder) with the new file that I have found it on the Internet or there is some other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`ContactCounts` is hidden from the public. Notice the `@hide` attribute in the source code of the class.

Source code: [`ContactsContract`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/ContactsContract.java)

You cannot use the hidden classes without extensive work and you will be vulnerable to the code being removed, not present, or changed in future or previous versions of the Android API.

You could try to copy the source code for the hidden class and use the local version of it in your project.

That means:

- Create a new file called ContactsContract.java in your project
- Copy the contents from the file linked above
- Rename the package to match your project
- Import your local class where the file is used

Answer (score 0):

Check this url for references 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html.

> > jar uf jar-file input-file(s)

Here 'u' means update.